# html5: Write content to a page without refreshing

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, html, dwr

I want to create a page where the top half contains start stop buttons and in the bottom half i want to write content from the server. the buttons invoke functions on the server and the server does some computing and generates timely messages which need to be written to the bottom half of the page.

Possible ways of doing
1. AJAX
2. DWR
3. HTML5

Let me know which method is better and how can i do it.

Comment: you've really got to be more specific than "teach me a technology".

Comment: Instead of saying, "tell me how to use these technologies," it would be better to say, "I have looked for tutorials on these technologies, but I'm not sure which ones are good.  Do you know of any quality tutorials on these technologies?"

Comment: I have been using dwr for last 6 months. Since you are using java, DWR could save lot of your production time. Its very easy to setup and use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AJAX

Means "Making an HTTP request without leaving the page". This will let you get content from the server. To write it you need to do DOM manipulation. There are no shortage of Ajax and DOM tutorials on the web

> DWR

Is a library to help with Ajax (although not one I've heard of before).

> HTML5

Is a now meaningless buzzword. Of all the meanings it has, only the ones which include "Ajax and DOM manipulation" will help, and that's already covered above.

Answer (score 0):

Look up a tutorial on xmlhttprequest. I know there is a good explanation of it here [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org). I am not sure where your current skill set is using HTML, server side programming, XML, and Javascript are, but you will need to have a minimum understanding of all of those in order to successfully implement AJAX.

There are lots of resources on the web, [Google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=ajax+tutorial&cp=5&qe=YWpheCA&qesig=UtQCyqiAdsHdBDd3KTAKBg&pkc=AFgZ2tma7WZz70wTRGISuWZ3JL8ORQ0OGmGcFh_D2IQVME1WbPZKfy7Yf35E3TjLmOKbjDGBZhUZ0VTcuYPucrtjwDHljzkf3Q&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=ajax+&pbx=1&fp=25a0b2344dc0e416)